# Polylang and woocommerce: How to translate currency symbol

Tags: woocommerce, polylang, woocommerce-currency-switcher

i want when i change the language to change my currency symbol. For example, to switch from dollar to euro but without changing numbers ...

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already solved this you may look at this code, provide by WPML.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    switch( $currency ) {
        case 'AED':           
          // if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
              $currency_symbol = 'AED'; 
           //}else{
             // $currency_symbol = 'د.إ';  
           //}
        break;            
    }
    return $currency_symbol;
}
```